# Changing the process name itself c++

Tags: c++

Does anyone knows how to make an executable file to change it's name while is running / at the start of the program.
I mean : Like the name of my executable file is 'Injector.exe'. I want that everytime when I run it to change it's name automatically(random).

Thanks.

Comment: For less than ethic reasons Im assuming

Comment: *Why* do you want/need to do this?

Comment: Created an Injector for cs:go (LoadLibrary).

Comment: Have you tried searching separately for how to generate random values, and how to set the name of a process on your target operating system?

Comment: @KABoissonneault, no, but I will try it rn thx.